# Box2D C++ - Why divide by 2?

Tags: c++, c, box2d

I was looking at a basic Box2D program, more specifically [this one](http://veeableful.wordpress.com/2012/02/16/tutorial-getting-started-with-box2d/).

Everything is fairly simple and makes sense, except for this line:

```
Shape.SetAsBox((32.f/2)/SCALE, (32.f/2)/SCALE);   // SCALE = 30
```

Now I know we divide by `SCALE` to scale 1m->30px but why is 32.f divided by 2? I don't understand why we divide by 2, if my box texture is 32x32 pixels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the [manual](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html) :

> groundBox.SetAsBox(50.0f, 10.0f);
>
> **The SetAsBox function takes the half-width and half-height** (extents)

Comment: @iccthedral explains it perfectly

Comment: @Ken Yeah, it looks counter-intuitive until you start working with global and local coordinate space, etc. It becomes natural after awhile.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the box is created around the center (0,0).

So,

```
x = (32.f/2)/SCALE;
y = (32.f/2)/SCALE
SetAsBox(x,y);
```

will create box with corners at (-x, -y), (-x, y), (x, -y), (x, y), so it will be of expected size.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the manual section 2.2 : http://www.box2d.org/manual.html#_Toc258082968

> The SetAsBox function takes the half-width and half-height (extents)

The consider the extend ("50 m on each direction") and not the width ("100m wide"). Hence the factor 2.